# Was Leo the Lion going to play the Cowardly Lion in The Wizard of Oz?

Tags: casting, the-wizard-of-oz

I once heard that originally Leo the Lion (the mascot for MGM) was going to play the Cowardly Lion in *The Wizard of Oz* (1939). Is this true? What happened? Why didn't he end up playing him?

Comment: He neither sings nor dances as well as Bert Lahr. I doubt this is true.

Comment: I can find multiple assertions to the real lion being *considered* but none of them have a citation or proof.

Comment: Perhaps Judy Garland was allergic to cats?

Comment: Perhaps Judy Garland and others int he cast were allergic to cat scratch fever?  Or big cat scratch fever?